# Is there a limit to the number of items that can be added using the Appearance Menus Screen?

Tags: admin-menu

I can add up to 17 items to my Menu. As soon as I add one more item by clicking the checkbox  for the page that I want to add in the Pages box in the left hand column and save the menu, the item that is last in the list drops off.

The [Appearance Menus Screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen) page in the Wordpress codex makes no mention of this limit.

I am using a child theme of the Thematic theme; but I have had this problem before with other themes too.

If there is a limit, is there anything that I can do to override this?

Comment: How many items do you have? How exactly are you adding items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could possibly be this bug http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134 and http://wordpress.org/support/topic/rc32-menus-still-crippled?replies=28 but 17 menu items is very low threshold.

**Try raising your php memory allocation** using FTP:

1) You can edit the memory_limit line in your php.ini (if you have access to that file) to 64M:

`memory_limit = 64M;`

2) If you can't get to the php.ini file, add this line at the top of your .htaccess file:

`php_value memory_limit 64M`

3) If that doesn't work or throws a "500 Internal Server Error", delete the line from .htaccess.

Then try adding the line below near the top of your wp-config.php file, right after the opening  `<?php`

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`

**If you have a php.ini,** also check and raise the execution time limits:

```
max_execution_time = 600

max_input_time = 600
```

**If the server is running suhosin,** try these new limits:

```
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000

suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
```

Comment: My memory limit was already set to 64MB. I have changed the max_execution_time and max_input_time too without effect. I see from the bug 14134 that Suhosin was causing the problem. I think that may be my issue too. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I added suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000 and suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000 to the php.ini file and that worked like a charm. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.